# R matching patterns: vector and column

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
vector_1 <- c('aa1/10', 'aa1/20', 'aa2/10')
```

And I have a data frame, with the column: product (some rows are empty)

```
product 
hello123

hello123;aa1/20
World
```

I want to have another column, called: check. 
If one of the values in my vector_1 is in the column product, then I want to have a 1, else a 0.

I tried different things, but they didn't work out:

```
df$check <- ifelse(df$product %in% vector_1, 1,0)
```

Unfortunately, no results... So I tried:

```
df$check <- grepl(vector_1, df$product)
```

But there I received an warning message: In grep: argument pattern has lenght >1 and only the first element will be used.

How can I solve this?

Result:

```
product            check
hello123             0 
                     0
hello123;aa1/20      1
World                0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df$check <- as.numeric(grepl(pattern = paste0(vector_1, collapse = "|"), x = df$product))
```